# linux : cut and compare two file names

Tags: shell, scripting

I've the below scenario

There are two files - sample.war & sample1.48.war
now, I've to cut only the first field of the first file. i.e., 'sample'. [I did this one with simple cut command]
Next, I've to count the total number of text in 'sample' and cut only those many characters in file 2 (sample1.48.war)
if these two characters matches , then do some operation & if not, some other operation.

Is there anyway we can do it ?

Comment: Yes, there is a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh                                                                                                                                                

a=`echo sample.txt|sed 's/\.[^.]*$//'`                                                                                                                        
b=`echo sample1.48.txt|sed 's/\.[.^]*$//'`                                                                                                                    
echo $a $b                                                                                                                                                    
len_a=`echo $a|wc -c`                                                                                                                                         
echo $len_a                                                                                                                                                   
cut_b=`expr $len_a - 1` // As the length of a will be 1 character extra due to the new-line so you have to cut b (length of a -1)                                                                                                                                      
echo $cut_b                                                                                                                                                   
sub_b=`echo $b|cut -c1-$cut_b`                                                                                                                                
echo $sub_b                                                                                                                                                   

if [ $a = $sub_b ]                                                                                                                                            
then                                                                                                                                                          
echo 'string matched' $a $sub_b                                                                                                                               
else                                                                                                                                                          
echo 'not matched' $a $sub_b                                                                                                                                  
fi
```

**Output:**

```
sh-4.3$ test.sh                                                                                                                                             
sample sample1.48.txt                                                                                                                                         

string matched sample sample
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @iamnew ... It really helped me lot. the part 'sub_b=`echo $b|cut -c1-$cut_b` ' is precisely what I was after. well done , you will be remembered :)